# 'SwiftClass' is unavailable: cannot find Swift declaration for this class - iOS Simulator only

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a swift class inside a Objc framework and when i try to use this universal framework inside my project it all works fine with a real device but as soon as i switch to simulator i get this error : 'swiftclass' is unavailable: cannot find Swift declaration for this class where swiftclass is my swift class inside the objc framework. I have checked similar post but nothing which talks about swift class inside objc framework. Also the moment i comment out this swift class useage in my project it again starts building fine with simulator as well.

Comment: You mean you mix objc and swift in a framework?

Comment: Yes, thats right a Objc framework which has a some new swift classes. As soon as i try building on device i see that my import "swiftmodulename" starts appearing in the framework header if I choose simulator the the import "swiftmodulename" just disappears from the framework header file and thats the reason my swift class is unavailable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the script which was causing the issue. I just had to make sure that my .framework/Modules/frameworkname.swiftmodule contains both arm64 and x86_64 files. In my case it was create another folder within it which never referred the x86_64 files.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same error and turned out that I had built my framework for a specific simulator. I changed the device  to `Generic iOS device` and did a `clean` and `build`, then I used the generated `.framework` file. Everything worked just fine after using this generated `.framework` file.

Comment: Tried this multiple times. This does not make any difference.